# Why am I getting an undefined method for 'plan' in my Devise Registration Sign Up page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Trying to add a subscription functionality to application with payola gem via the Devise controller.  When I click for the sign up page, the error message reads,

```
Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (7.7ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 34ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)

NoMethodError - undefined method `plan' for #<User:0x007f8d94acc9d8>:
activemodel (4.2.4) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb__2295071264192842435_70123012019120'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/Users/owner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:303:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
responders (2.1.0) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:236:in `default_render'
responders (2.1.0) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:170:in `to_html'
responders (2.1.0) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:163:in `respond'
responders (2.1.0) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:156:in `call'
responders (2.1.0) lib/action_controller/respond_with.rb:203:in `respond_with'
devise (3.5.2) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:10:in `new'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:49:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:59:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
```

Here's the Registrations/new.html.erb:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= render 'payola/transactions/stripe_header' %>
<% end %>
<div class="authform">
  <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :role => 'form',
    :class => 'payola-onestep-subscription-form',
    'data-payola-base-path' => payola_path,
    'data-payola-plan-type' => resource.plan.plan_class,
    'data-payola-plan-id' => resource.plan.id}) do |f| %>
 <h3>Sign up</h3>
<div>
  <br />
  <span id="error_explanation" class="payola-payment-error"></span>
  <br />
  <br />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label 'Subscription plan' %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:subscription_id, Subscription.all, :id, :name) %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true, class: 'form-control', data: { payola: 'email' }  %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %>
  <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil, class: 'form-control', data: { stripe: 'number' } %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= label_tag :card_code, "Card Security Code" %>
  <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil, class: 'form-control', data: { stripe: 'cvc' } %>
</div>
<br />
<div class="form-group">
  <%= label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiry" %>
  <%= select_month nil, { use_two_digit_numbers: true}, { name: nil, data: { stripe: 'exp-month' } } %>
  <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+10}, { name: nil, data: { stripe: 'exp-year' } } %>
</div>
<%= f.submit 'Sign up', :class => 'button right' %>
<% end %>
```

Here's my registration's controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
include Payola::StatusBehavior

def create
  build_resource(sign_up_params)
  plan = Subscription.find_by!(id: params[:user][:plan_id].to_i)
  resource.role = User.roles[plan.stripe_id] unless resource.admin?
  resource.save
  yield resource if block_given?
if resource.persisted?
  if resource.active_for_authentication?
    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
    sign_up(resource_name, resource)
    subscribe
  else
    set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"   if is_flashing_format?
    expire_data_after_sign_in!
    subscribe
  end
else
  clean_up_passwords resource
  render json:
    {error: resource.errors.full_messages.to_sentence},
    status: 400
  end
end

private

def sign_up_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email,
  :password, :password_confirmation, :plan_id)
end

def subscribe
  return if resource.admin?
  params[:plan] = current_user.plan
  subscription = Payola::CreateSubscription.call(params, current_user)
  render_payola_status(subscription)
end

end
```

Here's my Subscription Model:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
include Payola::Plan

has_many :users
validates :stripe_id, inclusion: { in: Subscription.pluck('DISTINCT stripe_id'),
  message: "not a valid subscription plan" }

def redirect_path(subscription)
'/'
end

end
```

Here's my config/routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
get 'content/member'
mount Payola::Engine => '/payola', as: :payola
root to: 'visitors#new'
get 'product/:id', to: 'products#show', :as => :products
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations'}
resources :users
```

EDIT:  Here's the user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 enum role: [:user, :admin, :member]
 after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?
 # after_create :sign_up_for_mailing_list

 belongs_to :subcription
 validates_associated :subscription

 def set_default_role
  self.role ||= :user
 end


 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable


 def sign_up_for_mailing_list
   MailingListSignupJob.perform_later(self)
 end

 def subscribe
    mailchimp = Gibbon::Request.new(api_key: ENV["mailchimp_api_key"])
    list_id = ENV["mailchimp_list_id"]
    result = mailchimp.lists(list_id).members.create(
    body: {
    email_address: self.email,
    status: 'subscribed'
  })
  Rails.logger.info("Subscribed #{self.email} to MailChimp") if result
end

def name
    [first_name, last_name].compact.join(' ')
end
```

end

Comment: Please post your `User` definition.

Answer (score 2):

You dumped a lot of code but didn't post the `User` model, which would actually give a better clue as to what you've done wrong.

Your problem is here:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :role => 'form',
    :class => 'payola-onestep-subscription-form',
    'data-payola-base-path' => payola_path,
    'data-payola-plan-type' => resource.plan.plan_class,
    'data-payola-plan-id' => resource.plan.id}) do |f| %>
```

`resource` is a `User` object.

You are trying to access a `plan` method, probably your `Subscription` model that you've defined.

In your User model, there should be this:

```
belongs_to :subscription
```

and you should be referring to your `subscription` this way:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :role => 'form',
    :class => 'payola-onestep-subscription-form',
    'data-payola-base-path' => payola_path,
    'data-payola-plan-type' => resource.subscription.plan_class,
    'data-payola-plan-id' => resource.subscription.id}) do |f| %>
```

I suspect you may have other issues with the rest of your application (why would there be many Users for a single Subscription?), but this would address your one symptom.

Comment: I uploaded to show you the user model.  I'm following a tutorial so you'll have to bear with me on my lack of knowledge.  I appreciate all the help very much though.

Comment: @twolips You didn't follow my suggestions though. Perhaps you should be posting the tutorial in the question and even perhaps contacting the developer of the tutorial.

Comment: I did as you instructed, referring to subscription the way you said and my user model already is already associated with the subscription model via belongs_to :subscription.

Comment: @twolips Good, but I'm not getting any feedback here - does it work now? Is it still broken? What's your new error? etc. Bear in mind that if the error is gone and your page loads, then the scope of your question should be considered solved.

Comment: The signup page still isn't loading and now it says that subscription is undefined. I thought part of the issue was that there was no new action defined in the registrations controller, but I didn't think I needed it because it inherits from Devise::RegistrationsController.

Comment: You probably don't have a `Subscription` set to `resource.subscription` - and something should set that up for you before loading the view. If you're truly following the tutorial to the letter, maybe it's time to find a new tutorial or contact the developer of the tutorial. It's very hard to help you when we don't have the instructions that you've been given.